# Set the max height of a css drop-down menu

Tags: css, height, drop-down-menu

How to set the max height of a css drop-down menu without using javascript?

My example is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dodoflying/wVsw4/)

There are many items in the drop-down menu. I want to set the max height and display scroll bar if there are too many items.

I tried to set

```
<ul id="nav" style="max-height: 500px;height:500px;">
```

But not works.

Thanks!

Comment: Add `overflow: auto`, but since your ul is actually wider than the Fiddle sub-window, the scrollbar will be hidden offscreen to the right. Your ul is larger than the whole subwindow. Adding `border: 1px solid blue;` to its style will show you that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just add "overflow: auto;" to the container: http://jsfiddle.net/wVsw4/1/

Answer (score -2):

Try adding to the style

```
 overflow:hidden
```

Comment: That code will hide the remaining part of the menu, it will not add a scrollbar. overflow:auto with max-height is the right answer.